# Update values with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a "shopping list" for a chef. Let's say he has the menu item Tuna Salad. His recipe is for 1 serving and has several ingredients. With javascript, how do I dynamically change the serving and it automatically change the amounts of the ingredients? This is my current code:

```
<?php include 'config.php';?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE id='$id'");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
include 'header.php';
echo "One serving of " . "<strong>" . $result['name'] . "</strong>" . " equals:";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing1Amt'] . " " . $result['ing1Mea'] . " " . $result['ing1'] . "  </li>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing2Amt'] . " " . $result['ing2Mea'] . " " . $result['ing2'] . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing3Amt'] . " " . $result['ing3Mea'] . " " . $result['ing3'] . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing4Amt'] . " " . $result['ing4Mea'] . " " . $result['ing4'] . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing5Amt'] . " " . $result['ing5Mea'] . " " . $result['ing5'] . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing6Amt'] . " " . $result['ing6Mea'] . " " . $result['ing6'] . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing7Amt'] . " " . $result['ing7Mea'] . " " . $result['ing7'] . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing8Amt'] . " " . $result['ing8Mea'] . " " . $result['ing8'] . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing9Amt'] . " " . $result['ing9Mea'] . " " . $result['ing9'] . "</li>";
echo "<li>" . $result['ing10Amt'] . " " . $result['ing10Mea'] . " " . $result['ing10'] . "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
include 'footer.php';
}
}
?>
<?php mysqli_close($con);?>
```

Comment: I don't see your Javascript code you've tried, but I do see that `$id` is not sanitized for safety.

Comment: @JeremyMiller I use mysqli_real_escape_string() in the form submission elsewhere. Is that not enough?

Comment: Unless you sanitize and put that back into `$_GET['id']`, then no, it's not enough.  And if you do, then that's bad practice.  If you know it's an `int`, for example, then `$id_sanitized = (int)$_GET['id'];` keeps you safe and you know it has been sanitized b/c of your variable naming.

Comment: @JeremyMiller I know this is completely off the topic, but will you point me where I can find more information about sanitizing? Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  The forum is about learning.  That question has been asked, actually.  I suggest reading the [higher-voted answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) as they address the question more completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript question is referred to as `AJAX`. Look up `jQuery AJAX`, you can load elements `onChange` or `onBlur` etc. You can also change elements based on selections if you do a form submission without javascripting. This will address your jQuery form. You will want to read up on it so you know what this is all doing:

**index.php**

```
<form id="recipes">
    <label for="recipelist">Recipes</label>
    <select id="recipelist" name="recipelist">
    <!-- HERE IS WHERE YOU LIST THE RECIPIES-->
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">Food <?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="2" name="serving_size" id="serving_size" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="ingredients"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#recipes').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    // You need to reference this page in the
                    // "lookup.php" whatever the page will be called
                    url:"lookup.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("#recipes").serialize(),
                    success:function(result) {
                        $("#ingredients").html(result);
                }});
                return false;
              });
            });
    </script>
```

**lookup.php**

```
// Do all your look ups and calculations
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to rewrite the code. I knew there was a way to prevent me from typing almost the same lines over and over. 

As far as changing the values, ideally, I would like for him to change "One" (make it an input variable) to any number and it automatically change the amounts of the ingredients.

Comment: So you want an input field that someone can type a digit or two and it will reload making calculations on that serving size? So if something says 1 serving = 1g you want him to be able to type 3 servings and changes to 3 g? Something like that?

Comment: Exactly. I know it's something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Ok so now the form will `serialize()` (basically it gathers all the data from the form fields) when the submit button is clicked and then send the whole thing to the `lookup.php` page. You will have to then create the code on the `lookup.php` page to return the correct recipe values and calculations.